# How to send user uploaded images using formData and Fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, form-data

I use the fetch API to send a put request with images, everything works up until the image. It says the following on the image fields:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
```

I assume I'm missing something.

```
const createPost = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let formData = new FormData()
        formData.append("author", userid)
        formData.append("needed_image", e.target.neededimage.value)
        formData.append("wanted_image", e.target.wantedimage.value)
        const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/createpost/', {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData
         })
    }
```

input fields

```
<div>
 <input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="neededimage" id="file" />
 <input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="wantedimage" id="file2"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access value, perhaps what you wanted to do is to access the files.

```html
<div>
 <input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="neededimage" id="file" />
</div>
```

With the above input tags, you can access the `files` property which is an IMMUTABLE array.

```js
const createPost = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("needed_image", e.target.files[0]);
    const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/createpost/', {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData
    });
};
```

Again remember that this array is IMMUTABLE therefore you can't modify the content directly. Also the `e.target.files[0]` is stored as a buffer therefore the returned data is a buffer stored in the `formData`.

Now as you said you have multiple `input` to deal with, so in this it is better to create a `change` handler and attach it both the inputs and use an outer `FormData` to append.

```html
<div>
    <input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="neededimage" id="neededimage" />
    <input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="wantedimage" id="wantedimage" />
</div>
```

```js
const neededImage = document.getElementById('neededimage');
const wantedImage = document.getElementById('wantedimage');

const handleFiles = () => {
  const files = [...fileInput.files];
  console.log(selectedFiles);
}

neededimage.addEventListener("change", handleFiles);
wantedImage.addEventListener("change", handleFiles);
```

One more thing since you want to upload multiple files it is better to allow them all in one input.

```html
<div>
    <input type="file" multiple accept="image/*" name="images" id="images" />
</div>
```

````js
function uploadMultipleFiles() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    const file = document.getElementById("images")    // all uploaded files
    for (let i = 0; i < file.files.length; i++) {
        formData.append(`image-${i}`, file.files[i]);
    }
}```
````

Comment: since I have two inputs with images, how would I target a specific one? Which input does **e.target.files[0])** target.

Comment: @devAR updated my answer, you can use multiple attribute to upload multiple files

Answer (score 0):

You can add state to store file and
your change function something like that:

```
  const [files, setFiles] = React.useState({
    neededimage: '',
    wantedimage: ''
  });

  const addImage = (e) => {
    setFiles((files) => {
      return { ...files, [e.target.name]: e.target.files[0] };
    });
  };
```

Add onChange for your inputs:

```
      <form>
        <input
          type="file"
          accept="image/*"
          name="neededimage"
          id="file"
          onChange={addImage}
        />
        <input
          type="file"
          accept="image/*"
          name="wantedimage"
          id="file2"
          onChange={addImage}
        />
      </form>
```

And then append `files` from state into you `formData`.

Comment: The OP is using vanilla JS, and you throw React JS at him??? Try to do what he is asking with vanilla js

Comment: The question has 3 tags: javascript, reactjs, form-data

Comment: how about reading the question rather than only looking at tags?? Not everyone on here is a tech genius. Some of us are trying to learn and ya'll always talk down and around us like we are supposed to know what we are doing already....

Comment: if my recommendation is not useful for you, you can just ignore it. And maybe it will be useful to someone else.